# Create Table Error: no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [Role]
(
     Role_Name nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
     Bssn nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT Pk_Role_Role_Name 
         PRIMARY KEY(Bssn, Role_Name),
     CONSTRAINT Fk_Role_Bssn 
         FOREIGN KEY(Bssn) REFERENCES Bandmembers(Ssn) 
             ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE Has
( 
    Role_Name nvarchar(20)NOT NULL,
    Bssn nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Pk_Role_Id_Ssn_Id 
        PRIMARY KEY(Bssn, Role_Name),
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Works_0N_Role_Name 
        FOREIGN KEY(Bssn) REFERENCES Bandmembers(Ssn) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Works_On_Bssn 
        FOREIGN KEY (Role_Name) REFERENCES role(Role_Name) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Error :

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Role' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'Pk_Works_On_Role'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: Can you at least edit your question to properly format your code? I tried but it's loaded up with `<br>` tags and I don't have the patience to edit every line.

Comment: You also need hep with your spelling :-) In any case, I suspect you'll need to have role_name as a key on its own, not just as the second part of the primary key. That seems to be what the error is saying - it would be a good idea to *read* the error messages you get very closely.

Comment: Your table `Role` has a **composite** primary key, made up from **two columns** - any foreign key referencing that **must ALSO have** these two columns. Referencing a primary key is an all or nothing approach - if you want to reference it, you must use **ALL** columns from that primary key - you cannot reference only parts of a primary key

Comment: Thanks guys. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table Has's foreign key is same with a references table's primary key.

```
CONSTRAINT Pk_Works_On_Bssn FOREIGN KEY (Bssn, Role_Name) REFERENCES [Role](Bssn, Role_Name)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the help